# Herr Doktor Professor, or Herr Professor Doktor?

Tags: politeness

The phrase

> Herr Doktor Professor

is relatively well-known amongst non-German speaking English-speakers. But assuming that all three words are used, what order is it in? Is it *Herr/Frau Doktor Professor* (what I assumed was the case, as it progresses from the most common to the least common honorific), or *Herr/Frau Professor Doktor*, as mentioned in [Is writing "Herr Prof. X" exaggerated/mandatory? Is it old-fashioned?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6792/is-writing-herr-prof-x-exaggerated-mandatory-is-it-old-fashioned)?

Comment: related, and with a good answer: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-is-the-correct-salutation-for-people-with-an-academic-grade-or-title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both *Professor* and *Doktor* are titles much like the historical *Freiherr*. Titles are added to the name in descending order, the highest ranking title first. Therefore, *Professor* **must** be placed before *Doktor.*

> Herr Professor Doktor Liebig …

However, it is rather uncommon to use *both* titles except in door signs and maybe the salutation of formal letters. Usually one would restrict oneself to one title in German.

> Herr Professor Liebig …

Note that for these intents and purposes, *Herr* and *Frau* do not count as titles. (Titles need to be gained but every grown-up is automatically either *Herr* or *Frau*; neither of them were ever explicitly gained. This was likely different two centuries ago.)

Comment: Are "Herr" and "Frau" titles? If so, why isn't it "Professor Doktor Herr"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm No, they are not ;) I’ll add that.

Comment: As @Jan already said "Herr" and "Frau" are not titles but salutations. Like Mr. or Mrs.

Comment: @chirlu Can’t agree that Mrs be obsolescent. My observation is rather that *all* females are automatically titled *Mrs*. *Mrs* is said a lot easier than *Ms*, and the latter can be much more easily misheard for *Miss*.

Comment: Freiherr is not a title anymore, it is part of the name: *Herr Professor Freiherr von Gunzenhausen*. Apart from that, peers (ie. two persons having the title *Professor*) may omit using their title altogether.

Comment: @Veredomon added a *historical* to the Freiherr. True, it is no longer considered a title in German.

Comment: Titles deriving from nobility were already mentioned; other titles (see.https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titularrat, Titularräte) did exist and still may do so e.g. in Austria. My personal idea would be to insert these after *Herr*.

Comment: The question also asked about addressing women where it’s a bit mor complicated, because one could either use _Frau Professor [Doktor]_ or _Frau Professorin_, but funnily _Frau Doktorin_ and _Frau Professorin Doktorin_ are not idiomatic (except among feminists), and neither is _Frau Doktrix_. In written German (unless in Austria), one should therefore use common gender-neutral abbreviations: _Frau Prof. Dr._ and _Herr Prof. Dr._ – as long as a name follows.

Comment: @chirlu I think that Mrs. is more common than Ms. Ms. is one of those things business schools seem to push. Also, yes I would write or say Mr. Professor Smith in an extremely formal situation-Mr. President. I am not sure it is safe to make your generalizations.

Answer (score 1):

To answer that question properly, one has to consider that Doktor is a academic grade, while Professor is an official title compareable to General or Bundeskanzler. This plays an important role not only inside Universities, where old traditions still regulate how two Professors have to approach each other, but also for daily use: To handle the so called "Professorenproblem", the [Munich University](http://www.zaar.uni-muenchen.de/studium/studenteninfo/student_prof/kommunikation/index.html) recommends, to write Professor in an extra line, separated from name and title, when adressing a letter.

> Herrn Professor
>
> Dr. Dr. h.c. mult. Claus-Wilhelm Canaris
>
> Adress

This is a contradiciton to DIN 5008, whish recommends to write *Herr. Prof. Dr. Faustus*. According to Munich Universitiy these two styles of adressing an professor allow for a separation between academics and non-academics.

In any case, the more honorable appelation *Professor* should be written before *Doktor* or *Dr.*

In oral communication, as well as in the appelation line of a letter, the Professor scores off the Doktor, so it is ok, to simply say "Herr Professor" without mentioning the Doktor.

As the title Professor is related to an employment as a Professor, special rules apply for retiered people. In most cases they may keep the title, but some institutions demand them to denominate themselfes *Emeritus* or *Prof. Emer.*